# How do I Increase swf video speed in gnash?

Tags: linux, gnash

Is there any way to increase the speed of a swf file? I couldn't find a good and fast way to convert it to video so as to increase its speed. I am using gnash to open swf files.

Comment: Do you use an extensible browser such as Firefox?

Comment: @extensible why is this related to my question?

Comment: Because if you use Firefox, for instance, there is an extension that allows you to download and convert any video stream into something that can be played back later on at any speed you wish. Just that Gnash doesn't do that, as far as I know. Could you describe what you did to download and convert the videos, by the way?